# MySQL check between date and time 2 colums

Tags: mysql

Have a problem to check if an entry exist between two DATETIME columns.
Creating a booking system for massages, i list times 08:00, 08:15 08:30, 08:45 and so on.
I want to check if there is a slot for example from 13:00:00 and two hours forward. (This treatment is 120 min, got other treatments with 90 min duration etc).

The table is like this

```
|id|event|from_date|to_date|

1 | massage | 2011-08-15 14:00:00 | 2011-08-15 16:00:00
```

the query

```
$times_from_date = '2011-08-15 13:00:00';
$times_to_date = '2011-08-15 16:00:00';

SELECT * FROM `wp_byforssell_booking` WHERE '". $times_from_date ."' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date OR '". $times_from_date ."' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date OR '". $from_to_date
```

It dosent work. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Lets say i got the appointment in my database as above.

I want to Query all the appointments between 2011-08-15 13:45 and 2011-08-15 15:30.

That is my problem. Hope that is a better explanation to the problem.

**EDIT**

My table looks like this now

```
id|event|from_date|to_date|

1 | massage(60min) | 2011-08-15 13:30:00 | 2011-08-15 15:30:00

2 | massage(60min) | 2011-08-15 09:00:00 | 2011-08-15 10:00:00
```

And my Query: 
Select time från 09:30 and 11:30, and it dose not produce row#2.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_byforssell_booking WHERE((('2011-08-15 09:30:00' <= from_date)AND('2011-08-15 11:30:00' > from_date)) OR (('2011-08-15 09:30:00' >= from_date)AND('2011-08-15 11:30:00' < to_date)))
```

Comment: BTW in your example youre checking for **three** hour slot, not **two** - `13:00` till `16:00` is three hours.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.  You declared `$times_to_date` but your query uses `$from_to_date`.

```
...BETWEEN from_date AND to_date OR '". $times_from_date ."' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date OR '". $from_to_date
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Should be:

```
...BETWEEN from_date AND to_date OR '". $times_from_date ."' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date OR '". $times_to_date
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Michael points out, you're also doing the same WHERE clause twice:

```
... WHERE '". $times_from_date ."' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date OR '". $times_from_date ."' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date ...
```

Isn't one of them supposed to check `$times_to_date`?

Comment: Yeah i saw that, but that was just a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to list all buckets where there's enough time difference between a start time and an end time (in this case $times_from_date and $times_to_date) and this will do it, I think:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_byforssell_booking 
WHERE exists 
      (select 1 from wp_byforssell_booking where   
      timestampdiff(HOURS,from_date,to_date)>=
      timestapdiff(HOURS,$times_from_date,$times_to_date)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, think i need to start over. Check the EDIT in my post

Answer (score 0):

To get records which do overlap with datetime ranges given with `$times_from_date` and `$times_to_date` you use query like

```
SELECT * FROM wp_byforssell_booking WHERE
(
(($times_from_date <= from_date)AND($times_to_date > from_date))
OR
(($times_from_date >= from_date)AND($times_from_date < to_date))
)
```

You might have to use `<` instead of `<=` and `>` instead of `>=` - that depends on your logic, ie does two events overlap if one ends at `2011-08-15 14:00:00` and other starts at `2011-08-15 14:00:00` (IOW is it required to start `2011-08-15 14:00:01` in order to not overlap).